# Why is bake action creating weird rotation?

Tags: animation, rigging, baking

I have an object that's animated using a Follow Path constraint. Follow curve is checked. Everything works great.

[image: Zipper following curve]

BUT I need to export this animation via FBX. I'm thinking that `Bake Action` is the best way to do that. But unfortunately, when I try to bake the action I get all kinds of weird rotation as the object passes around corners.

[image: Bad rotation on zipper]

Any ideas as to how I can get proper baked animation?

For those interested, my bake settings are:

```
[X] Only Selected
[X] Visual Keying
[X] Clear Constraints
[ ] Clear Parents (I've tried it both ways. No luck.)
[X] Overwrite Current Action
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by "Gimbal Lock". To correct for it, switch the rotation mode from XYZ Euler to Quantarion and then rebake.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that this had something to do with the rotation axis; I don't understand more than that.

I was able to fix it by rotating the object, applying the rotation, and using different `Forward` and `Up` settings in the Follow path modifier.